# Make tab second tab clicked default

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have tabs that has first tab clicked default. How to make the second tab clicked instead of first tab:

```
<div id="tabs_menu" style="display: block;">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <a track="'floodlight':'lgsta649'" href="#Features" id="tab_feature_content" class="track-processed tab_active" name="tab_feature_content">
              <span>Features</span>
          </a>
      </li>

      <li>
          <a track="'floodlight':'lgsta278'" href="#Gallery" id="tab_gallery_content" class="track-processed" name="tab_gallery_content">
              <span>Gallery</span>
          </a>
      </li>

      <li>
          <a track="'floodlight':'lgsta648'" href="#Specs" id="tab_spec_content" class="track-processed" name="tab_spec_content">
              <span>Specs</span>
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `selected` option:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: 1 }); // Initially select the second tab.
```

Comment: @user928238: Could you post the JavaScript you're using in the original question?

Comment: The code above is already there in the site. I am using like this to select second tab by default . When I do this the tabs was hiding. .<script>
$(function(){
$( "#tab_feature_content" ).tabs({ selected: 1 });
});
</script

Comment: @user928238: I'm not sure what you mean by "the tabs was hiding." Is the tabs content not showing up? Does it show up when you click off the tab and back on?

Comment: @user928238: Are you loading the content via AJAX? If so, are you loading it using the built-in functionality?

Comment: The tabs code is already there. I am using Adobe test and target to execute it,and see the changes the site.